# Validating empty restful response array using restassured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Sometimes GET call is returning `[] empty array`. I can use `.body(size)`, but I do not want to use hard assertions.

It can be empty or have an array of objects, so I want to use if condition to make a decision to proceed further based on empty/not empty.

The code is as below:

```
given().when().get(url).then().body("[0].name",equalTo(value‌​))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code?

Comment: thanks for reply.  I am using given().when().get(url).then().body("[0].name",equalTo(value)) .  but when it is empty it's throwing cannot get name on null object illegal argument error

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the below way

```
Response res = given().when().get(url);
if(!(res.body().asString().equals("null"))
{
   // do what you want to check or action
}
```